# Swift iOS Scrolling View When Keyboard Is Visible

Tags: swift, scroll, uitextview

In my view I have two text fields and one text view.  The text fields aren't hidden by the keyboard but the text view is.  No problem.  I can scroll it.  The issue I'm having is that if the keyboard is already visible the keyboardWillBeShown event doesn't occur.  My text view is visible enough to be tapped on when the keyboard is up but I want the entire field to scroll into view.  Since keyboardWillBeShown won't fire (since the keyboard is already shown) how can I scroll the field?

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out.  Just had to add the scrolling code to the begin editing event.